# Problem with Local ArcGIS Server used with local Web AppBuilder

Tags: arcgis-server, wfs, arcgis-web-appbuilder, proxy

At the beginning I will describe what I did:

1. I installed ArcGIS server on WM on my computer. Then I published WMS and WFS on the server.
   I can connect to WFS and WMS in my local network and display it using eq. QGIS with: https://192.168.1.55:6443/arcgis/services/shetches/MapServer/WFSServer
2. I downloaded the ArcGIS Web AppBuilder (Developer Edition) ZIP and followed all whe steps in the tutorial:
   https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/getstarted.htm

I entered http://localhost:3344/webappbuilder as URL and
Redirect URIs:
http://localhost
https://localhost
http://desktop-auvhne   (my computer name)
https://desktop-auvhne

3. I ran Web AppBuilder and created a simple app with AddData Widget:
   https://desktop-auvhne3:3344/webappbuilder/apps/3/

If I try to add WMS by URL everyting works fine and WMS is displayed: https://192.168.1.55:6443/arcgis/services/wms2/ImageServer/WMSServer

(When I pasted the above URL into the form field I got a warning:

> Please enter a URL starting with https:// or http://

, but WMS was displayed)

**There is a problem with WFS:**

If I try to https://192.168.1.55:6443/arcgis/services/shetches/MapServer/WFSServer I get the same warning:

> ```
> Please enter a URL starting with https:// or http://
> ```

but this time it works partly.

I see in devTools that requests for getCapabilities and describeFeatureType works fine: eg. https://desktop-auvhne3:3344/proxy.js?https://192.168.1.55:6443/arcgis/services/shetches/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS&request=GetCapabi...

Layer with WFS is added, but there is an error with getFeature.

> POST
> https://desktop-auvhne3:3344/proxy.js?https://192.168.1.55:6443/arcgis/services/shetches/MapServer/WFSServer
> net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

In Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS console i see:

> Error: Argument error, options.body

How to fix it? What have I done wrong? I am not familiar with web technologies

Comment: As a test - can you try adding just the regular MapService using the AddData widget. (This ensures its not a WFS specific problem. If that fails, its probably an overall configuration issue.)

Comment: I tried with sample WFS  and I noticed in devtools that request does not use proxy and looks: https://dservices.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/services/JapanPrefectures2018/WFSServer with some body. If I try with mine the request looks like: https://desktop-auvhne3:3344/proxy.js?https://192.168.1.55:6443/arcgis/services/shetches/MapServer/WFSServer and there is an error with options.body. I tried to make a post request via Postman without proxy and i get correct answer. I dont understand why proxy is used for my url